# Remove .jsp from page names

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have some jsp page in my web application and the following code (for each jsp page) inside my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This setting removes the `.jsp` from my page url and i can open `/login` like `/login.jsp`

Actually this setting make my jsp page acts like a compiled servlet.

Is there anyway to do this for all of my jsp pages without writing this settings for each page? I need some kind of url rewrite.

Comment: well in this way how you write form action .Do you write <form action="login.jsp" or <form action="login">

Comment: you can use both of them. my choice is second one.

Comment: See in my app i am using response.sendRedirect("login.jsp") so in the url it shows login.jsp. well does your technique will be helpful if i want only login instead of login.jsp

Comment: In my technique you have to use "login" instead of "login.jsp" and "login.jsp" is not disabled or redirected to "login". I need a better way.

Comment: so I would write response.sendRedirect("login");

Comment: @javaBeginner this will help you but dont forget that login.jsp is also a valid page name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41342/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-s-yavari)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a common filter and handle request and forward to respective jsps
I have writter with annotations which can be written inside web.xml if you are using a older version of servlets.
    
        CommonFilter
        com.filters.CommonFilter

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CommonFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here all requests are forwarded to respecive jsps.
eg.. if url is /login , it will be forwarded to /login.jsp , or if it is /home then to /home.jsp ... all urls are just treated as jsp files, But you can filter urls as per your requirement

```
package com.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebFilter("*")  // give your url mapping  eg..//you can write for "/yoururlspec/*"
public class CommonFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String path="";
        if (request.getRequestURI().length() > request.getContextPath().length())
        {path=request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length()+1, request.getRequestURI().length());
        req.getRequestDispatcher(path+".jsp").forward(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works fine for me:

```
package filters;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;

@WebFilter("*")
public class URLFilter implements Filter {
    HashSet<String> invalidExts = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        invalidExts.add(".css");
        invalidExts.add(".js");
        invalidExts.add(".img");
        invalidExts.add(".png");
        invalidExts.add(".jpg");
        invalidExts.add(".jpeg");
        invalidExts.add(".gif");
        invalidExts.add(".woff");
        invalidExts.add(".woff2");
        invalidExts.add(".ttf");
        invalidExts.add(".eot");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String context = request.getContextPath();
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        String qStr = request.getQueryString();

        if (!uri.endsWith("/") && uri.length() > context.length() && isPage(uri)) {
            if (uri.endsWith(".jsp")) {
                String path = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf(".jsp"));
                if (qStr != null && qStr.length() > 0)
                    path += "?" + qStr;
                response.sendRedirect(path);
            } else {
                String path = uri.substring(context.length()).replace("-", "_");
                req.getRequestDispatcher(path + ".jsp").forward(req, res);
            }
        } else chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    private boolean isPage(String uri) {
        boolean result = true;
        String ext = null;

        if (uri != null) {
            if (uri.contains("."))
                ext = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("."));

            if (ext != null && invalidExts.contains(ext))
                result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).

Follow the instructions in [UrlRewriteFilte Manual](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html).

Comment: I used it once but i can not find the right configuration/rule! Would you please help me to write the rule i want?

Comment: While this may be correct answer [link only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/186652). Please improve your answer by including essential parts regarding this question (for example from tutorial).